# Inno Setup - Create folder in Public Users Documents in Windows 10

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to add a folder to an installation which will eventually hold user output data. I can't put a folder into Program Files because users will not have the required permissions to write to it.

If it is not being installed to `Program Files`, then the data folder can be created inside the application folder (this is working fine).

I have a little piece of code to detect whether the installation was made to Program Files and, if so, I wanted to use `CreateDir()` to make a data folder in `C:\Users\Public\Documents\{'MyAppName}\DB` This seems to fail, in `[Code]` even though the standard Inno Setup script works:

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{commondocs}\{#MyAppName}\DB"
```

I am using the `DeinitialiseSetup()` procedure to make this happen at the end of installation, once the path is definite.

This is my code:

```pascal
[Code]
  procedure DeinitializeSetup();
  begin
    { If it has been installed in the Program Files Folder put DB in Public Documents }
    if Pos(ExpandConstant('{pf}'),ExpandConstant('{app}')) > 0 then                       
    begin
      if not CreateDir (ExpandConstant('{commondocs}\{#MyAppName}\DB')) then
        MsgBox('Error: Data folder could not be created.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    end
      else
    begin
      if not CreateDir (ExpandConstant('{app}\DB')) then
        MsgBox('Error: Data folder could not be created.', mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
     end;
  end;
```

Following another SO suggestion I used:

```
PrivilegesRequired=lowest
```

in the script but it did not work with or without this. I am beginning to think this may be a permissions issue but am not sure why, as the installer standard `[Dirs]` script works fine.

This is not the same as the other questions regarding identifying the path - I have got all the paths I want, only: `[Code] CreateDir()` does not seem able to create a folder in `{commondocs}`.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: @MartynPrikryl Many thanks for making that so much better with your edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the `{commondocs}\{#MyAppName}` does not exist. [`CreateDir` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createdir) can create a single directory only. It won't create parent folders for you, if they do not exist (contrary to `[Dirs]` section entry).

You can use [`ForceDirectories` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_forcedirectories) instead:

> Creates all the directories along the specified directory path all at once.

---

Side note: Do not use `DeinitializeSetup` to create the directories – Is is triggered even if the installation fails, or even if the user cancels the installation.

Use [`CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged):

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    { Your code }
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Force Directories did the trick as per your answer and you are right - I also wasn't happy with `Deinitialisesetup()` but couldn't get the `CurStepChanged()` function to work only started a couple of days ago with Pascal and Inno. Thank you all working well.